# how to move wsp's from one server to another server using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, solution-package

I have a requirement to move all WSP's from Local Machine to QA server using PowerShell. Any links please.

Answer (score 1):

First you should prepare the list of solutions that are deployed in your local machine. For that you can go into Central Admin - System Settings - Solutions

From here list down the WSP names.

Now you can use following PowerShell to download each WSP to your local folder

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$file = $farm.Solutions.Item("wspfilename.wsp").SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs("c:\install\wspfilename.wsp")
```

Now copy folder `c:\install` to QA and use below PowerShell to install those

```
Add-SPSolution c:\install\wspfilename.wsp
```

Now you can deploy the solution using

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity wspfilename.wsp –WebApplication http://QA
```

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/12/02/adding-and-deploying-solutions-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Actually my requirement is: I have 4 wsp's in d:\test folder(local Machine) i need to move them to \\QA\d$\test folder(QA Machine).

Comment: Can't you use xcopy command that is available as part of windows?

Comment: Or you can use `Move-Item` PowerShell cmdlet - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176910.aspx

Comment: thanks. i found this link here.http://www.surinderbhomra.com/blog/post/2012/04/26/My-First-PowerShell-Script-Moving-Files-From-One-Directory-to-Another.aspx